# Touchpad & keyboard not detected

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, touchpad, hardware

I've just bought Lenovo Ideapad 320s-14ast with AMD A9-9420 and i want to install elementary as my first os here. But unfortunately it can't detect my touchpad and keyboard. I can't even just move my cursor and type something in keyboard so i can't install it. In GRUB they worked fine, though. Anybody knows the solution?

Comment: Im having almost the same problem but only the touchpad doesnt work. My laptop is Lenovo ideapad 320 15IKB. Could you solve the problem??? I've already tried some commands at the terminal, but nothing worked. Fingers crossed here!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a solution but I found some hints at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948439/touchpad-not-detected-on-lenovo-ideapad-320-with-kubuntu-17-04). Just try if something works for you.